# Geth getPendingTransactions and subcribe pendingTransactions return nothing

Tags: go-ethereum

I have installed geth on my server and I think it's fully synced but I can't get any pending transactions using either `web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions')` or `web3.eth.getPendingTransactions() // it's return empty array []`

I've tried calling `web3.eth.isSyncing()` method and it return

```
{
  currentBlock: 11339249,
  highestBlock: 11339249,
  knownStates: 635215876,
  pulledStates: 635215876,
  startingBlock: 11338769
}
```

So my node is fully synced right ?

I've also tried `txpool.status` on geth console, it return 0 on both object

```
{
  pending: 0,
  queued: 0
}
```

This is my geth configuration on config.toml

```
[Eth]
NetworkId = 1
SyncMode = "fast"
DiscoveryURLs = ["enrtree://AKA3AM6LPBYEUDMVNU3BSVQJ5AD45Y7YPOHJLEF6W26QOE4VTUDPE@all.mainnet.ethdisco.net"]
NoPruning = false
NoPrefetch = false
LightPeers = 100
UltraLightFraction = 75
DatabaseCache = 512
DatabaseFreezer = ""
TrieCleanCache = 256
TrieCleanCacheJournal = "triecache"
TrieCleanCacheRejournal = 3600000000000
TrieDirtyCache = 256
TrieTimeout = 3600000000000
SnapshotCache = 0
EnablePreimageRecording = false
EWASMInterpreter = ""
EVMInterpreter = ""
RPCGasCap = 25000000
RPCTxFeeCap = 1e+00

[Eth.TxPool]
Locals = []
NoLocals = false
Journal = "transactions.rlp"
Rejournal = 3600000000000
PriceLimit = 1
PriceBump = 10
AccountSlots = 16
GlobalSlots = 75000
AccountQueue = 64
GlobalQueue = 1024
Lifetime = 10800000000000

[Node]
DataDir = "/home/ubuntu/.ethereum"
IPCPath = "geth.ipc"
HTTPHost = "0.0.0.0"
HTTPPort = 8545
HTTPVirtualHosts = ["*"]
HTTPModules = ["net", "web3", "eth", "txpool", "rpc"]
HTTPCors = ["*"]
WSHost = "0.0.0.0"
WSPort = 8546
WSOrigins=["*"]
WSModules = ["net", "web3", "eth", "txpool", "rpc"]
GraphQLVirtualHosts = ["*"]
```

also currently my `.ethereum` folder usage is `293.3 GB`
Geth Version: 1.9.24-stable

Comment: What does `web3.eth.blockNubmer` return? It is synchronized if it is always very close to last block published on block explorers.

Comment: how did you generate the config.toml file? and what argument did you pass to add "txpool" and "rpc"?

Answer (score 0):

The `web3.eth`'s `getPendingTransactions` method returns an empty array because it's returning only transactions originating from an account on your node. Here's [the source code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ead814616c094331915b03edd82d4200a7880178/internal/ethapi/api.go#L1700) (assuming you are on Geth).

You can use `eth.subscribe` to get all the pending transactions:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const url = 'wss://ENDPOINT';
const web3 = new Web3(url);

var options = {
    address: null,
    topics: [
        null
    ]
};

var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', options, function(error, result){
    if (!error) console.log('got result');
    else console.log(error);
}).on("data", function(log){
    console.log('got data', log);
}).on("changed", function(log){
    console.log('changed');
});
```

[This might be useful too](https://support.chainstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/900003426246-Subscribing-to-global-new-pending-transactions-with-web3-js).